# Subconsultas en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar subconsultas en mongoose, tengo dos colecciones una llama *lugar* y otra *material*, la colección *lugar* tiene un arreglo de los id de los *materiales* agregados por un *usuario*.

Ahora lo que intento hacer es que se pueda actualizar un lugar solo si el atributo de la colección material *asignado = false*, de otra forma no sera actualizado, después de agregar el material al lugar este material deberá ser actualizado *asignado = true* para que  ya no se pueda agrega a otro lugar.

A continuación dejo mis esquemas:

```
// Material
const materialSchema = new Schema({

    title: { type: String, required: [true, 'El titulo es necesario'] },
    url: { type: String, required: [true, 'La url es necesaria'] },
    asignado: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
    rating: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0, max: 5 },
    usuario: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Lugar
const lugarSchema = new Schema({

    nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'] },
    materiales: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Material',
        required: false,
    }],
    usuario: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Algo así quiero hacer:

```
    let id = req.params.id;
        var body = req.body;
        const user = req.currentUser._id;

        let lug = {
            nombre: body.nombre,
            materiales: body.materiales,
            usuario: req.currentUser._id
        };

        const mat = body.materiales;

        // buscar los materiales que se van a agregar al lugar solo si asignado = false
        await materialModel.find({ _id: mat }, { asignado: 'false' }, (err, guardado) => {
                // actualiza solo si asignado = false 
                // y guardamos la referencia del material en el lugar
                await lugarModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, lug, { new: true });
        });

        // actualizamos el material para que no se pueda agregar después
        // query aquí
```

Forma en la que meto los datos por ahora

[image: Forma en la que meto los datos por ahora]

Relación entre las colecciones
[image: Relación entre las calecciones]

Comment: porfa agrega la coleccion que tiene actualmente con los campos minimos, luego agrega el resultado del find que quieres hacer

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu comentario, el find es para buscar entre el arreglo de materiales agregados para después solo permitir los que tiene el atributo asignado = false y después realiza el update del lugar solo con los materiales antes encontrados.

Comment: `Resultado del find:  [ { asignado: false,                             
    _id: 5b746e44a1e65a13781789a1,      
    title: 'Impresora',                          
    usuario: 5b70d0881c04b3529c795f7c,  
     },                           
  { asignado: false,                    
    rating: 4,                          
    _id: 5b74898dd22d773210456e6a,      
    title: 'Librero',                             
    usuario: 5b70d0881c04b3529c795f7c  } ]                          `

Comment: De verdad no explicas como es la relacion entre cada uno , de verdad esta pregunta puede ser muy interesante pero por lo pronto no entiendo el problema

Comment: Acabo de subir una imagen para que me puedas entender, ya no se de que otra manera explicar mi duda.

Comment: en conclusion quiere mostrar los datos del usuario en tu consulta?

Comment: aqui un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45567/28035

Comment: No quiero mostrar los datos del usuario, lo que quiero hacer es buscar en la colección de material y dependiendo el contenido de un documento realizar una actualización pero en otra colección (lugar)..

Comment: Hola @yvan, hay un posible error en el primer 'find', cuando colocas como segundo argumento '{asignado:'false'} lo que estas realizando es un 'project' y no un filtro, si lo que necesitas es buscar todos los materiales que tienes y con el valor 'asignado = false' deberías realizar la consulta de esta forma:
`await materialModel.find({ _id: mat , asignado: 'false' },{}, (err, guardado) => {
               if(guardado)
                   await lugarModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, lug, { new: true });
        });`

Creo que el problema estaba ahi, podrías comprobarlo y confirmarme.
Gracias